# tower of hanoi prolog

Tags: prolog, towers-of-hanoi

Hello i have a problem with my implementation of the tower of hanoi.
I need to print a list of list with the necessary moves, but my algorithm just work when the numbers of discs is N=1.
This is my code

```
move(1,X,Y,_,L) :-  
    append([X],[Y],L).
move(N,X,Y,Z) :- 
    N>1, 
    M is N-1, 
    move(M,X,Z,Y),
    move(1,X,Y,_), 
    move(M,Z,Y,X).
```

And this is the result when N= 1.

```
?- move(1,left,right,_,L).

L = [left,right]

(16 ms) yes
```

i need something like this

```
    L = [[left,center],[left,right],[center,right],[left,center],[right,left],
      [right,center],[left,center],[left,right],[center,right],[center,left],
[right,left],[center,right],[left,center],[left,right],[center,right]]
```

When N=4

please if someone could help me i will be gratefull.

Comment: If this is your code exactly as you have shown here, notice that the first clause of `move` has 5 arguments, while the second clause has only 4 arguments. I am almost certain that this is a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some small changes you could write:

```
move(1,X,Y,_,[[X,Y]]).

move(N,X,Y,Z,L) :- 
    N>1, 
    M is N-1, 
    move(M,X,Z,Y,L1),
    move(1,X,Y,_,L2), 
    move(M,Z,Y,X,L3),
    append(L1,L2,L4),
    append(L4,L3,L).
```

Example:

```
?- move(4,left,right,center,L).
L = [[left, center], [left, right], [center, right], [left, center], [right, left], [right, center], [left, center], [left, right], [center, right], [center, left], [right, left], [center, right], [left, center], [left, right], [center, right]] ;
false.
```

Comment: Glad that helped!!

Answer (score 3):

When describing **lists** in Prolog, always consider using **[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)** notation!

For example, consider:

```
moves(1, X, Y, _) --> [X-Y].
moves(N, X, Y, Z) -->
    { N #> 1,
      M #= N-1 },
    moves(M, X, Z, Y),
    moves(1, X, Y, _),
    moves(M, Z, Y, X).
```

Note that this...

- uses *fewer* arguments
- *avoids* the use of `append/3`.

I have also taken the liberty to use...

- the name **`moves//4`** to make clear that we are describing *moves*, not a *single* move.
- **CLP(FD)** constraints for declarative arithmetic (easier to understand)
- `(-)/2` for denoting **pairs**, as is the convention in Prolog.

---

Sample query, using the **`phrase/2`** interface predicate for DCGs:

```
?- phrase(moves(4,left,right,center), Ls).
Ls = [left-center, left-right, center-right, left-center, right-left, ... ].
```

Comment: Awesome answer ,note that the result was meant to be list of lists and not list but it is more clear this way....

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement! Yes, I have taken the liberty to use pairs instead. To use lists of lists, one only needs to change the first rule, replacing `X-Y` by `[X,Y]`, which is however the term `'.'(X, '.'(Y, []))` and thus somewhat wasteful in comparison to `-(X, Y)`.